# "Cannot find symbol" of variable passed through method

Tags: java, netbeans, constructor, compiler-errors

[image: Screenshot showing error]

Why am I getting an error when referencing a variable that is being passed through the constructor?

Here is the complete Customer.java class:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class Customer {

    // SQL Variables
    private final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/books";
    private final String USER = "root";
    private final String PASSWORD = "P@ssw0rd1";

    // Class Variables
    int CustomerID;
    String customerEmail;
    String customerPassword;
    String customerFirstName;
    String customerLastName;
    String customerAddress;
    String customerCity;
    String customerProvince;
    String customerPostalCode;
    String customerPhoneNumber;
    String customerCreditCardNumber;
    String customerExpiryDate;
    String customerCreditCardType;

    // Class Constructors
    public Customer(int customerID) // Constructor for an Existing Customer
    {
        ResultSet customerData = MySQLQuery("select * from Customers where CustomerID=" . customerID);
    }
    public Customer(HttpServletRequest post) // Constructor for a new customer
    {

    }
    // Constructor Methods
    public ResultSet MySQLQuery(String query)
    {
        return queryResultSet;
    }
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

This is a Java Web Project created in NetBeans 7.3 in a Customer.java class inside the default package.

Comment: Java string concatenation is different from PHP, you must use `+` to concatenate strings, instead of `.`

Answer (score 5):

You appear to be using a `.` when you meant a `+`.

Perchance an old PHP programmer? :-)

Comment: damnn beat me by 1 second